# get stat from all tabs on window close

Tags: javascript, html, function, events

Is there any way to trigger 'beforeunload' event for each tab where window.addEventListener initialized with that event when user just close browser window, without closing each tab by itself? For each tab I'm using this mechanics:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'Controller.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send( 'data=' + encodeURIComponent('json_handle_example') );

}, false);
```

I don't need any messages and pop-ups which can disturb user, verything should happen in the background. I want to save collected data from each opened tab, but as for now it only works with each tab close, nor with whole browser windows closing. If user closing browser window with my several tabs - info from them losts.

Maybe there is any way to detect browser window closing and send data from all my opened tabs via 'beforeunload' event?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API)

> Unlike requests made using XMLHttpRequest or the Fetch API, the browser guarantees to initiate beacon requests before the page is unloaded and to run them to completion.

Comment: But it guarantee that request will be just sended, but not ONLY WHEN tab is closed or the whole browser window....right?